# BASH statement always returning true when using OR

Tags: bash

I've got the following **NODE_ENV** set to **testing**. I can't figure out why, but for some reason this IF statement is always returning true (even if I set the NODE_ENV = testing).

```
if [[ $NODE_ENV != "testing" || $NODE_ENV != "development" ]]; then
  echo "❌  Not a development OR testing environment: NODE_ENV is not set to development OR testing"
  exit 1
fi
```

How could this be happening?

I also tried formatting the if statment like `if [] || [];` which didn't work either.

Comment: Yes because it matches 2nd condition `$NODE_ENV != "development"` and returns true

Comment: Also you could just simplify it to `if [[ ! $NODE_ENV =~ ^(testing|development)$ ]] ; then` using the regex operator that `bash` supports with the `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you want uses AND here, rather than OR:

```
if [[ $NODE_ENV != "testing" && $NODE_ENV != "development" ]]; then
    echo "❌  Not a development OR testing environment: NODE_ENV is not set to development OR testing"
    exit 1
fi
```

The opposite of:

```
$NODE_ENV == "testing" || $NODE_ENV == "development"
```

is:

```
$NODE_ENV != "testing" && $NODE_ENV != "development"
```